# Unpredictable change on UseIIS value (VS2015)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

From time to time, after my check-ins on TFS, my colleagues complain that I am changing the **UseIIS** value from **true** to **false** on the project's CSPROJ:

```
<UseIIS>true</UseIIS>
```

becomes:

```
<UseIIS>false</UseIIS>
```

But this change is totally unpredictable. It doesn't happen everytime I do check-in. This last time, I noticed that I have done an 'unload project' + 'load project' before checking-in.

However, I have just repeated right now that operation in order to check for a possible change on the UseIIS but nothing changed.

I have searched on Stackoverflow but I was unable to find any connection with my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to un-check "Apply server settings to all users" under `Project Properties > Web` pane:

[image]